# onclick changing percenatge of div colour fill

Tags: html, colors, onclick

I am creating an interactive survey and have a containing div that shows the % of users answers (agree/disagree) in 2 colours. I require the div to alter % depending on users answer.

How can i achieve this using onClick?

Any help  would be great.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a container div containing 2 elements (agree and disagree), you can alter their widths dynamically.  By wiring an onclick event up to adjust this, you should be able to get the results you need:

```
$(".vote-agree-button").click(function() {
    $(".agree").width($(".agree").width() + 1);
    $(".disagree").width($(".disagree").width() - 1);    
});

$(".vote-disagree-button").click(function() {
    $(".agree").width($(".agree").width() - 1);
    $(".disagree").width($(".disagree").width() + 1); 
});
```

Worked JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/d8QLa/

Comment: Happy to help! If you're happy this is resolved, please select this as your answer!

Comment: Eeeey - Thanks Pickle.  Now I know - and knowing is half the battle!